# I Need a regex which can match these two patterns "/enpoint" or "endp/enpoint"

Tags: javascript, regex, endpoint

i have a file which has endpoints like this `"/enpoint"` or `"endp/enpoint"` it need to match these two patterns and grep the endpoints

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```js
(endp)?\/endpoint
```

Here is a link to the online regex playground for the above expression.
https://regex101.com/r/I2GuF8/2